# Facebook Application page post to MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm working on an iframe app with MVC3. Right now, I'm accesing the link https://apps.facebook.com/cotizacionsed/ but, as you can see, there is a first post given by the form that is loaded with this html:

```
<form action="/auto/ResultadoCotizacionAsyncFacebook?CodigoPostal=0&amp;Rastreo=False&amp;TieneGnc=False&amp;codIa=0&amp;valuacionIa=0&amp;AnioNum=0&amp;EsCeroKm=False" method="post">
```

But if I access to the url, the tag is loaded like this:

```
<form action="/cotizador-facebook" method="post">
```

Do you know why is this? When I access the url alone, I don't get the errors.

Adding the controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Seguros/Auto/ResultadoCotizacionAsyncFacebook
    public ActionResult ResultadoCotizacionAsyncFacebook(FormularioAuto solicitud)
    {
        if (!WebMisc.Validations.ValidationsMethods.IsEmailAddressValid(solicitud.Email))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "El Email es inválido");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ResultadoAuto resultadoAuto = (new Sitio.Code.Companias()).GetResultadoCotizacionModel(solicitud, ViewBag);

            var auto = solicitud.Anio.Split(';');
            solicitud.Marca = auto[0];
            solicitud.Modelo = auto[1];
            solicitud.Anio = auto[2].StartsWith("0") ? DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() : auto[2];
            solicitud.EsCeroKm = auto[2].StartsWith("0");

            var zona = solicitud.Localidad.Split(';');
            solicitud.Provincia = zona[0];
            solicitud.Localidad = zona[1];
            solicitud.CodigoPostal = (new GrupoMono.CodigosPostales.Service()).GetCodigoPostal(solicitud.Provincia, solicitud.Localidad);
            solicitud.Departamento = (new GrupoMono.CodigosPostales.Service()).GetDepartamento(solicitud.CodigoPostal);

            resultadoAuto.Formulario = solicitud;

            var infoautoSvc = new GrupoMono.InfoAuto.Service();
            resultadoAuto.SumaAsegurada = (infoautoSvc.GetValuacion(solicitud.Marca, solicitud.Version, int.Parse(solicitud.Anio)) * 1000).ToString("N", Nfi());
            ViewBag.CodigoInfoAuto = infoautoSvc.GetCodigoInfoAuto(solicitud.Marca, solicitud.Version).ToString();
            Session["ResultadoAuto"] = resultadoAuto;

            try
            {
                using (var historico = new GrupoMono.HistoricoCotizaciones.Service())
                {
                    historico.SaveContactoAuto(solicitud.GetContactoAutoParaHistorico());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new MailerController().ErrorLog("Histórico Tiró Error", ex).DeliverAsync();
                Log("Historico", "Ha ocurrido un error: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace, null);
            }

            ViewBag.referrer = TempData["urlreferrer"] != null ? TempData["urlreferrer"].ToString() : "Acceso Directo";

            return View("ResultadosAsyncFacebook", resultadoAuto);
        }
        else if (solicitud.codIa == 0)
        {
            ViewData["Marcas"] = (new GrupoMono.InfoAuto.Service()).GetMarcas().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x });
            ViewData["Provincias"] = (new GrupoMono.CodigosPostales.Service()).GetProvincias().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x });
            return View("CotizarAsyncFacebook");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Marcas"] = (new GrupoMono.InfoAuto.Service()).GetMarcas().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x });
            ViewData["Provincias"] = (new GrupoMono.CodigosPostales.Service()).GetProvincias().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(solicitud.Modelo) && solicitud.Modelo.Contains(";")) solicitud.Modelo = solicitud.Modelo.Split(';')[1];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(solicitud.Anio) && solicitud.Anio.Contains(";")) solicitud.Anio = solicitud.Anio.Split(';')[2];
            return View("CotizarAsyncFacebook", solicitud);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CotizarAsyncFacebook(FormularioAuto solicitud)
    {
        if (Session["urlreferrer"] != null)
        {
            TempData.Add("urlreferrer", Session["seguimiento"].ToString());
        }

        if (solicitud.codIa == 0)
        {
            return View("CotizarAsyncFacebook");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ResultadoCotizacionAsyncFacebook", solicitud);
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think we need much more information.  I'm not even sure what to ask because you have provided too little info.  How about you give us the code from your controller to start?

Comment: Ok, adding the code misc man.

Comment: is there any javascript in your views (other than the validation scripts)?  I'm curious if there's an ajax call or something being submitted.

Comment: No..., all I can tell you is that the iframe form is presented like this (post type..., don't know why...) <form action="/auto/ResultadoCotizacionAsyncFacebook?CodigoPostal=0&amp;Rastreo=False&amp;TieneGnc=False&amp;codIa=0&amp;valuacionIa=0&amp;AnioNum=0&amp;EsCeroKm=False" method="post"> ...